# Differences between Desktop Wordpress dev console and iPhone Safari browser window

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I'm having a problem with Wordpress. I've styled my website in the customize console in Wordpress on my Desktop, but when I open it with my iPhone (can't confirm if this is happening with other mobile browsers) there is this gray border on the outside of the block. Here's a screenshot:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/M8Ffb.jpg

I can't find any information about this or find anything about other people having this issue. Is there some way to access the source code or Inspect tool in mobile Safari? Just trying to make the block fill the screen.

Comment: Well I've managed to fix that issue, but now I have whitespace to the right of the webpage that seems to have no reason to exist.

Comment: please share the solution for original question

Comment: also please include attachement in question and code with style you have issue with